# Is there any difference in the meaning of these two sentences?

Tags: meaning, difference

Is there any difference in the meaning of these two sentences?

- We're going to be meeting there on a regular basis.
- We're going to meet there on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

In this case progressive and the simple future have identical meanings, and may be used interchangeably. Both are valid. Both should b correctly understood by a fluent speaker. The difference is only one of style.

Comment: I really wouldn't care which form I use, I might easily use either. In fact  I probably have used both forms at one time or another.